# What to do with the dead thread (not a deadlock)?

Tags: windows, multithreading, networking, architecture, operating-system

In our application there is a subsystem listening for file system changes, including those over the network. Sometimes, probably when the network is under stress, a listening thread can get stuck. I emphasize, that the discussion here is not about deadlock caused by incorrect thread synchronization. Thread get stuck either in a very first call to `CreateFile`, or in a subsequent call to File System API. The question is, what to do with such a thread.

I can determine that a given thread is inactive during some period of time, and to terminate it. But authoritative people say it is very bad, though I do not understand why to keep a dead thread is better than to terminate it. Then I thought, that I could at least release some resources allocated in the thread, for example, file handles.

So I created a thread-cleaner, which closes file handles and frees memory allocated by the dead thread. But soon I was amazed to find, that the cleaner thread got stuck itself in a call to `CloseHandle` API. I was really shocked, since I was sure that `CloseHandle` cannot get stuck.

Now I'm completely at a loss, because if the application continues to work long enough, and the network or part of it still has problems, then I can end up with many dead threads, holding a lot of system resources!

Comment: I don't know who those "authoritative people" are, but perhaps you misunderstood what they told you.  Forcefully stopping a thread is bad when you can not know what state it's in, what locks it may have locked, what files it may have open etc.  But you are not proposing to _stop_ a thread.  You are asking how to destroy a thread that already has stopped for reasons that you can not control.

Comment: @james, But I indeed cannot know what state the stopped thread is in! Executing an I/O request, it could internally enter some critical section I'm not aware of. And if the `CloseHandle` accesses the same critical section, this can explain why my "Cleaner" thread was stopped as well. So all the cautions that you mentioned are applicable to my case also.

Comment: The fact that a thread has stopped when it should not and you don't know why is a Bad Thing.  No doubt about that.  I am only saying that you probably will not make the situation any worse by destroying the stopped thread.

Comment: 'you probably will not make the situation any worse by destroying the stopped thread' - I would not bet on that.

Comment: 'a listening thread can get stuck' - how many listening threads do you have?  Monitoring file system events on networked drives is, well, not the most reliable subsystem ever, even with only one listener.   Anyway, when this listening thread gets stuck, does that not critically affect your app?  What do you do after it's stuck - create another thread to do the same monitoring?

Comment: If it's just stuck/blocked, using no critical resources or CPU at all and it's not preenting your app from functioning, I would suggest just setting some 'suicide' flag that will cause it to terminate itself if it ever returns from [whatever], and just orphaning it, forgetting about it forever.

Comment: I mean, how often does it get stuck and have to be replaced, or whatever you do to recover?

Comment: @Martin, Now I redesign and re-implement the entire subsystem, and my question is part of rethinking of the problem. Currently we have one listening thread; if it does not respond within some timeout, it is killed and a new one is launched. This new thread is trying to resume listening of the same directories which were monitored before, and often get stuck itself. The problem is occurred at big customers having complex network, here in-house it happens rather rare.

Answer (score -1):

> "Thread.Sleep(0) is occasionally useful in production code for
>   advanced performance tweaks. It's also an excellent diagnostic tool
>   for helping to uncover thread safety issues: if inserting
>   Thread.Sleep(0) anywhere in your code makes or breaks the program, you
>   almost certainly have a bug."

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-19.aspx

Comment: your answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: hi, I know that ... but maybe this will solve the stuck issue ... so no dead thread any more ... I'm still researching on this subject ... good luck.